# How to set segment to view in codeigniter after form validation?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I am validating a form on many view that are generated by the third URL segment.

The URL: http://example.com/listings/item/12 (*The 12 will change based on item*)

Both my functions are below, **my question is, when the validation fails how to I refresh the page with the 3rd segment and show the validation errors?**

P.S: I have already tried redirect() but the validation errors don't remain.

Thank You.

---

This is the "item" function

```
    public function item()
{

    if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
    {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->load->model('listings_model');

        if ($data['things']= $this->listings_model->get_item($id))
        {
            $this->load->view('list/item_view',$data);
        }
    }
    else
    {
         $this->unauth();
    }
}
```

---

This is my validations

```
    public function get_email()
{

    $this->load->library('form_validation');


        $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'required|trim|callback_check_captcha' );


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
           $this->item();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->model('listings_model');

            if ($this->listings_model->update_listing())
            {
                echo "Good";
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: have you put `<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>` in your view?

Comment: Yes I have but the redirect gets rid of that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to redirect to your page when error occurs. you can put it in your controller when error occurs.

```
redirect('listings/item/12/error_message_goes_here', 'location');
exit;
```

And in your view check weather the fourth parameter exists. if the fourth exists then show the error

```
if(!empty($this->uri->segment(4))){

   $this->output->set_output($this->uri->segment(4));

}
```

So you the point is: you redirect and in your redirect you pass the error message, then in view if error message exists  you display it.

Comment: Thank I ended up setting a session variable if it passed to show it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set uri segment by setting form action attribute.

```
form_open("controller/method/segments/to/retain", array('method' => 'post'));
```